# How to use if(checkbox.checked) to disable a particular javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently experimenting with a script, and I want to add a checkbox to allow user to either activate it or not, based on their preference.

I've simplified the sample to show only the script that I need to turn on/off (the one that makes other buttons unclickable depending on which is specified.)

How it should work is:

if the checkbox is **checked**, **allow** script.

if the checkbox is **unchecked**, **disable** the script (make this script inactive and allow users to use the tool however they want).

However, I cannot complete the part that will add a checkbox functionality. Here's what my code looks like:

```js
function enabledisablebuttons() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("enabledisablecheckbox");
    //Should I add another var in here?

    function resetallamnotes() {
        document.getElementById("1st").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("2nd").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("3rd").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("4th").disabled = false;
    }       

    function amnotesDisable1st() {
        document.getElementById("1st").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("2nd").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("3rd").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("4th").disabled = true;
    }
    function amnotesDisable2nd() {
        document.getElementById("1st").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("2nd").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("3rd").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("4th").disabled = false;
    }
    function amnotesDisable3rd() {
        document.getElementById("1st").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("2nd").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("3rd").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("4th").disabled = true;
    }
    function amnotesDisable4th() {
        document.getElementById("1st").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("2nd").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("3rd").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("4th").disabled = true;
    }

  if (checkBox.checked == true){
  
    //What to enter here
    
  } else {
  
    //And also here
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="enabledisablecheckbox">Checkbox:</label> 

<input type="checkbox" id="enabledisablecheckbox" onclick="enabledisablebuttons()">

<br>

<button class="cbtn" onclick="resetallamnotes()">Reset</button>

<br><br>
        
<button id="1st" onclick="amnotesDisable1st()">1</button>
            
<button id="2nd" onclick="amnotesDisable2nd()">2</button>
            
<button id="3rd" onclick="amnotesDisable3rd()">3</button>
            
<button id="4th" onclick="amnotesDisable4th()">4</button>
```

I'm really new to coding, especially JS, but I really really need this feature now to work. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Code in `onclick` attributes is executed in the global scope. It can't reference functions that are defined inside another function.

Comment: All those functions need to be defined at top-level, not inside `enabledisablebuttons`

Comment: Woah, thank you for the useful information there, sir. However I don't know how to implement the change needed for it to work or look in almost the same way.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want. I don't think there's a way to disable all JavaScript. How would you undo it, since it would disable the JS that runs when you uncheck the box?

Comment: If you just want to disable all the buttons, you can do it similarly to the way you enable all the buttons in `resetallamnotes()`.

Comment: These buttons above are just samples, and the real ones will insert a specified text in the ```textarea``` onclick. Now I added this feature that will make some of them "unclickable" if they are not applicable to the one you've recently clicked. All I really need is a way to turn on/off this feature via checkbox, just in case the user doesn't want this feature that disables buttons upon clicking a button, in other words, be able to freely click on any button that will insert the text they need, just like the old version of the tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to expose a variable to keep track of your "should I execute?" state. If you are working with a version of JavaScript that supports classes, I would also recommend wrapping your code in a class.

```
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("enabledisablecheckbox");
    var shouldExecute = checkBox.checked === true;

    function enabledisablebuttons() {
        // Coerce the value to be truthy
        shouldExecute = checkBox.checked === true;
    }

    function resetallamnotes() {
        if (!shouldExecute) {
            return;
        }

        document.getElementById("1st").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("2nd").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("3rd").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("4th").disabled = false;
    }       

    function amnotesDisable1st() {
        if (!shouldExecute) {
            return;
        }

        document.getElementById("1st").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("2nd").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("3rd").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("4th").disabled = true;
    }
    function amnotesDisable2nd() {
        if (!shouldExecute) {
            return;
        }

        document.getElementById("1st").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("2nd").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("3rd").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("4th").disabled = false;
    }
    function amnotesDisable3rd() {
        if (!shouldExecute) {
            return;
        }

        document.getElementById("1st").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("2nd").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("3rd").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("4th").disabled = true;
    }
    function amnotesDisable4th() {
        if (!shouldExecute) {
            return;
        }

        document.getElementById("1st").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("2nd").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("3rd").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("4th").disabled = true;
    }
```

Additionally, if you wrap all of your `button`s in a `fieldset`, you can disable only the `fieldset` and all of the child `button`s will automatically be disabled (as opposed to individually disabling all of them).

Comment: This solution looks really interesting and might be the one I need. However I don't understand yet some of your suggestions (still not able to learn this). I tried pasting the script together with my HTML and it's not working. I have no clue what I missed?

Comment: I had an unmatched bracket at the end of the snippet. I've corrected it.

Comment: Thank you so so much! Yaay I can finally move on to the next steps. Thank you!